# How to read a file path from a cell to send an attachment?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I can send multiple files with different lines

```
.Attachments.add ruta1
.Attachments.Add ruta2
```

[image: My worksheet example]

But I don't know how many files are going to be sent.

I tried the following code:

```
With correo
    .To = Range("F" & i)
    .Subject = Clientes.Range("K2")
    .Body = Range("k6") & " " & Range("D" & i) & "." & vbNewLine & Clientes.txt_mensaje
    
    j = 6
    Do While Cells(j, 14) <> Empty
        .Attachments.Add Cells(j, 14)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    .Send
```

I get:

> "Run-time error '438' occurred:
> The object does not support this property or method".

The error occurs in `.Attachments.Add Cells(j, 14)`

[image: When I run the procedure]

My code complete here:

```vb
Sub envioCorreo()
    Dim ulfila As Integer
    Dim correo As Object
    ulfila = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ruta1 = Range("N6")
    ruta2 = Range("N7")
    ruta3 = Range("N8")
    ruta4 = Range("N9")
    ruta5 = Range("N10")
    For j = 6 To Range("N11").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox "ruta" & j - 5
    Next j
    For i = 2 To ulfila
        Set correo = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        With correo
            .To = Range("F" & i)
            .Subject = Clientes.Range("K2")
            .Body = Range("k6") & " " & Range("D" & i) & "." & vbNewLine & Clientes.txt_mensaje
    
            For j = 6 To Range("N11").End(xlUp).Row
                .Attachments.Add "ruta" & j - 5
            Next j
            .Send
        End With
      
    Next i
    Set correo = Nothing
    MsgBox "Se han enviado " & i - 1 & " correos con éxito"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? What does `does not work` means? Is there an error? if so, which line?

Comment: @RaymondWu Thank you very much for your quick response. Sorry, I think my query was not well executed. When I run the procedure, I get: "Run-time error '438' occurred:
The object does not support this property or method".

Comment: Your "complete code" seems to be different than your screenshot and previous snippet.. which is the correct one?

Comment: Can you try `.Attachments.Add Cells(j, 14).Value`  instead?

Comment: Yes, I was doing several tests, I tried four different codes.

And I think I know what happened, it seems that Attachments.Add does not accept cell values ​​directly, but specific paths like "C: \ ... \ name.pdf" or that these addresses are inside a variable.

I share what I did in case someone else can use it in the future  `        For j = 6 To Range("N11").End(xlUp).Row
            Path = Cells(j, 14).Value
            .Attachments.Add Path
        Next j`

Comment: If I understand correctly, passing `Cells(j,14)` as a argument can be interpreted as passing the `Range` object instead of it's default property (`Value` in this case) so the error comes from the fact that `Attachments` object does not have a `Add` method with a `Range` parameter. Good to know you solved it!

Comment: It may be that, the truth is that I did not take into consideration that I was taking it as a range object and not its value. Thank you!